# VBA PowerPoint - Disable keyboard keys?

Tags: vba, keyboard, action, powerpoint

I need to know how to disable the keyboard during the presentation because I don't really want people to skip around the PowerPoint but rather interact with it. I just want to disable the buttons that let's people move around slides such as the arrow keys and the space bar.

Comment: Can't they just skip slides with the mouse instead? This is a problem which will likely be awkward and difficult to solve with VBA. You'd probably be better off remapping keys temporarily: http://goo.gl/6fXTG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an option that would mostly disable the keyboard, and disable built-in mouse navigation. 
These instructions are for Powerpoint 2007 or 2010:

1. Go to the `Slide Show tab`.
2. Select `Set Up Slide Show`.
3. Under Show Type, select `Browsed at Kiosk (full screen)`.
4. Hit `OK`.

Note: 
Once the slideshow is started the only key that will do anything is Esc, which will end the show. 
A standard mouse click will no longer advance slides, you will need to use VBA, Hyperlinks, or timers to advance slides.

For more information, here are instructions on [creating and distributing a self-running PowerPoint presentation](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-a-self-running-presentation-3caf0cef-7cda-40f1-ab7a-f161a1a91d93?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN).